# Java method unidentified for the type

Tags: java, swing

I am coming from C++ to Java and all I'm trying to do is write a method. I dont understand why I'm getting: method 'setFrame(String)' is unidentified for the type 'BillUtility'
Any help is appreciated.

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class BillUtility 
{

public static void main(String argc[])
{
    setFrame("Bill Utility");
}

public setFrame(String title)
{
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setTitle(title);
    frame.setSize(800, 1000);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}

}
```

Comment: Your "method" is missing a return type, and it isn't a `BillUtility` constructor.

Comment: `public void setFrame(String title) {...` is probably what you meant.

Comment: @bradimus Yes thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You need to add "static void" to your method header. A static method calls other static methods, so since main is declared as static, setFrame must be as well. You declare void when the method is not to return a value.

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify a return type. In your method, It would be `void`.
I think there are return types in C++ too, am I wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 problems here:

First is that you are missing a return type in the method header.

Second: is that you deal with main method as local method that has access to BillUtility class, But it's not .

You need to create an object from BillUtility class and use it call setFrame method or set the setFrame method header to be static.

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class BillUtility
{

    public static void main(String argc[])
    {
        BillUtility util = new BillUtility();
        util.setFrame("Bill Utility");
    }

    public void  setFrame(String title)
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setTitle(title);
        frame.setSize(800, 1000);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues in your code.

1. You need a return type for method `setFrame()`. In this case it will be

   ```
   public void setFrame(String title)    //set return type as void
   ```
2. If you want to invoke `setFrame()`, either you make it `static` (which I don't think this is a suitable situation) or you create an instance first, then invoke `setFrame()` from the instance:

   ```
   BillUtility bu = new BillUtility();  //create an object of BillItility
   bu.setFrame("your title");           //invoke setFrame() from object
   ```
3. It is recommended to invoke `setVisible(true)` as the last statement when implementing your JFrame.

You may also want to invoke `frame.pack()` and set the dimension of your JPanel (which goes into your JFrame) instead of setting the size for your JFrame manually.

Comment: @PedZad Take a look at my answer.